# The Tezos-client err! I need help

Tags: tezos-client, error, sandbox

The Ubuntu in Windows10.I try to install tezos-client , but I input in ubuntu for tezos-client it worning say :[image] ,What can I do .
ps:my english so bad, but I try read!

Comment: that could indicate that no node is running for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't appear to have a node running locally. `tezos-client` needs to connect to a node in order to execute transfers, etc. Either start a node, or use the flag `--endpoint https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io/` to use a public remote node.

Comment: OK ,Thx for your answer! I try it.

Comment: I try to this code --endpoint https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io , The err  does not exist.
But I try again this code tezos-client  the err is  exist ，I dont understand ! execute one  again and I try anythig ?

Comment: @Roger you must always supply that flag unless you are running your own local node.

Comment: @Roger At least around the time of Delphi it was possible to save these settings in the config via command line, to avoid having to type it everytime. Check out the commands in "Setting up CLI" of my tutorial, but use the same URL you have above, not the old one in the docs: https://gitlab.com/camlcase-dev/tezos-rpc-postman

Comment: @utdrmac THX  I try it. THX for your answer!!